# Japanese word for a specific definition of "writing"

Tags: word-requests

I had been thinking about the invention of writing in human history when I realised I didn't know its Japanese translation.
What would be the closest word for the following definition of "writing":

> Writing is a medium of human communication that involves the representation of a language through a system of physically inscribed, mechanically transferred, or digitally represented symbols... - [1]

I have come across 筆記 and 執筆, but judging from their dictionary and Wikipedia entries, 筆記 seems to be the closest one [2].

---

References:

- [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing
- [2] [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/筆記](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AD%86%E8%A8%98)

Comment: I think [文字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97) is the word normally used in that context. One translation of 'writing system' is 書字システム.

Comment: @sundowner That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @sundowner in the comments, [文字](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97) is the word I was looking for.

I corroborated the claim by googling up `文字歴史`, getting the answers one would expect from "the history of writing".